# How disable XAMPP or PHP caching?

Tags: xampp

After I reinstalled XAMPP and copied the projects folder into htdocs and ran the script to create the database I have a rare case of cache. This is something that I have done on other occasions without problems.
Regardless of the changes you make to the code, a previous version is always displayed without the changes.
I clean the browser cache... no changes. I ruled out that the problem was in the browser, because I used two other browsers where I had never opened the page and the version showed is the same without the changes.
In PHP I have the headers to avoid the cache:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); // HTTP/1.1    
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
```

In httpd.conf I commented the line of:

```
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
```

Without success... I installed an older version of XAMPP and the problem remains.

Some suggestion, please??
Regards

Comment: Without sharing more details, it's impossible to provide help. Are you sure that it's not your application itself that sets the headers?

Comment: Hi Nico, let me know what king of information will be necessary, please... I really appreciate your help, but this is driving me crazy